# Can I video job interviews?

Tags: interviewing, social-nuances

Well I'm currently looking for a job, however the last 10 (so this is a good time to review it) interviews all apparently went "poorly", the result was; "we found a better candidate". Even though apparently there's a huge lack of people who try to work in my field.

Now I have no idea why they went poorly and I always had the feeling everything was amazing during the interview. So to me it's a real surprise. Now I do have difficulty seeing social "hints" or subtleties, doubly so when under stress. (And I'm literary shaking from stress during a job interview, if I'm not getting a blackout - but that's just something I can't solve quickly).

Now to get "better" at this I need to have an objective look: and while practice with friends/family my friends always state I'm doing "fine", apparently I am not: so to review this, would it be acceptable to put a camera while I go to a job interview so I can review myself later?

Comment: Do you ask for feedback post interview? This may help.

Comment: Have you tried recording the practice interviews?

Comment: `And I'm literary shaking from stress during a job interview, if I'm not getting a blackout - but that's just something I can't solve quickly`. Your question about video actually seems like a red herring here: the real issue is that you have a near-uncontrollable stress reaction to interviewing. Having video of yourself reacting this way doesn't change the fact that, regardless of how long it takes, you're going to need to solve this issue. So I would focus on how you can do that rather than trying to get an interviewer to agree to being recorded.

Comment: Stop. Just because they offered someone the job does not mean it went poorly. It just means that of the 5-10 people they interviewed, you were at best #2. IT could have gone terrific and you convinced them you are 9/10 on all the skills they need, and they would have hired you, but another candidate was 10/10 on one or more. What evidence do you have that it went poorly other than them hiring someone else? Why do you reject the evidence from family and friends?

Comment: @dlev while true I'm visiting a psychologist for that, however she said it will be something of the "long breath (implying multiple years if possible at all)" before I see any improvements and should expect/stress myself to improve faster. Yet I kind of need a job within that time.

Comment: @paul23 I'm glad to hear that you're seeking assistance with that! I don't mean to imply that you should cease job hunting until you've got it under control, I was more trying to point out that, as described, it seems like you know what you're going to see on video. In the meantime, I think everyone's advice about doing mocks with family/friends (that you can trust to be honest!) is the best way to simulate getting video, since I think your odds of getting any actual interviewer to agree are very slim. Best of luck!

Comment: You don't list your location, but if you have any kind of employment services in your locale (such as the Job Centre here in the UK), perhaps see if they offer interview training sessions. You're likely to get more useful feedback in such a session than from friends and family.

Comment: I agree with @KateGregory - hiring is like house hunting. I looked at lots of houses. There were many that were *really great* - but I still only get to live in *one.* That doesn't suddenly mean that all the rest of them were terrible, and eventually they will all have new owners, too.

Comment: Also - your friends/family are probably poor mock interviewers. Consider getting in touch with some third party recruiters if you haven't yet. They are typically very hungry to place candidates and more than willing to do mock interviews and/or coach candidates. Also, if you have a higher ed degree, you may want to reach out to your school's careers counseling office. Many schools provide career support for your lifetime, not just while you're enrolled and looking for your first job after school.

Comment: @dwizum (and others), Of course I test with videos, and of course I don't just test for familie (though I do for the "job specific" exercises).  But I apparently behave complete as a different person when I'm relaxed and while I'm in a situation where there is a difference in power level. (Part of the reason why my previous two psychologists "failed", as they kept saying I didn't behave normally in front of them, even though for me I did).

Answer (score 11):

> would it be acceptable to put a camera while I go to a job interview so I can review myself later?

Without asking? Absolutely not. It's never appropriate to video people without asking. (Even if it's legal, it's still not appropriate).

You can of course ask, and if they give permission, you can do it. But don't wait with asking until you are in the room with the interviewers. Ask the moment they contact you to set up an appointment. That gives them the opportunity to check their policies and/or legal department.

Now, if you would be interviewing with me, I'd deny that request. For a couple of reasons:

- All our meeting rooms have windows and/or glass doors. I don't want you to record my coworkers; their privacy is important. Every now and then, recordings happen at our offices (for training, PR, recruiting, etc). The company goes above and beyond protecting the privacy of its employees, making sure noone gets recorded who does not want to get recorded. If the company goes out of its way, there's no way a random interviewee can make recordings.
- Most offices have big screens displaying graphs relevant to the jobs of the teams sitting near to them. That is often sensitive information.
- We may discuss things which should remain between us. I'd be far more careful in answering any of your questions if the interview is being recorded.
- I'm not in the business of training you to do job interviews. If you see the interview as "doing practice", I've better things to do with my time.
- I don't know where the recording ends up. I may say something which, taken out of context, or by using some clever editing, may make the company I work for (or myself) look bad.
- It will probably violate the GDPR in more ways than I can think of.
- I just hate being recorded.

Comment: And cameras of any kind might not be allowed at the facility for any number of reasons. Pull out a camera in my office, and I have to call security to come take it (and you) away.

Answer (score 5):

> would it be acceptable to put a camera while I go to a job interview
>   so I can review myself later?

Acceptable is whatever the other party will accept.

I suppose it's possible that some potential interviewer would allow a video recorded interview. But I don't know of any hiring manager who could consent to that. Certainly I never would. There is no upside for the interviewer, and potential downsides as far as legal liabilities and general lack of comfort. I suspect asking for permission to record the interview would start things off on exactly the wrong foot.

If you actually want the job, I would suggest you skip the idea of a recording of an actual job interview. Instead, video record your practice interviews with your friends and review them with a critical eye.

Your friends, although well intentioned, aren't as invested in your interview success as you are. A response of "fine" may mean that they think you are doing a fair job but it could be better. It might mean that they don't want to upset you so just reply with "fair". Either way, you are in a better position to judge if you are coming off the way you hope.

As @Nelson wisely suggests, you might consider paid services for your interview skills.

Comment: There are probably paid services that will critique your interview skills and train you on it.  It costs money but they're, literally, in the business of improving your interview skills.

Answer (score 2):

**I would not.**

When you go for interview, you act like you are the best candidate for the job, and you are definitely going to be hired. You show full interest, and when you ask questions, you talk in a way, you are going to be hired.

So why should someone going to be hired ask to record the interview? It only shows you are not confident you are going to get the job. Moreover a lot of people will think you are here for a practice mock interview, and not really interested in the job.

So what you should:

- Practice mock interviews with friends/family only.
- Once you get hired, improve your interview skills further by participating in interviews as an employee for the company. That way you will also see the other side, and learn from other candidates.

Comment: +1 for getting rid of the bit about Skype interviews. It's now a decent answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm in a similar situation with engineering. Graduated in 2014 with excellent academics, work experience and extracurriculars but never stood out. Feedback was along the lines of keep trying/you will find something eventually if you persevere/you were a bit quiet. I felt I had put in a lot of effort and made myself into a well rounded graduate, following most of the advice regarding being employable but there just seemed to be better candidates, despite a so called shortage. Ended up just tying myself in knots trying to be someone I wasn't by following the so called interview tips. If you are naturally quiet or reserved the worst thing you can do is to try and be loud and outgoing etc. I took rejection pretty badly as well tbh as you get labelled as "must have a toxic personality" or "a really terrible or lazy person" to be unemployed with an engineering degree. In reality as long as there's multiple grads (and other entry level candidates) with 2:1s and similar backgrounds applying to the same vacancy its quite easy to fall short on required social/interpersonal skills. Happens just by being a bit awkward or struggling to think of good answers on the spot under that kind of pressure, that's just how it goes and I would do the same in an employers shoes.

Fast forward a couple years, worked in retail/medical manufacturing so people skills have improved. I still apply to engineering jobs now and again and now finding things are easier by just being myself. Was able to record a one-way video interview this week quite confidently. What has helped most is getting a stable job/relationship so there isn't as much pressure. It's a "nice to have" now as opposed to before when you're unemployed and just racking up rejections it can seem like you're in a worse situation than you really are.

Comment: Speaking from the employer/hiring manager's side of the equation, I think I need to point out the other side of the story you're telling in your first paragraph. Yes, it may seem like you get a lot of rejections, or a "negative" stigma because of "failed interviews," but the reality is, pretty much no one just walks in to their first interview, aces it, and gets that job. In other words, what you and the OP are labeling as "failure" is, often, just a part of the process. **Most people** interview lots of times before getting the job they want. Some times over months or years.

Comment: In addition, hiring managers won't inherently know (or care) if you've been on one interview, or a hundred, prior to sitting down at their table. They're going to care about how you do in **their** interview. There's really no such thing as a candidate getting a "bad reputation" because they haven't been hired by other companies. The good news is: every hiring process is a fresh start and a new chance. Learn as you go, react to the results, fine tune your process, maybe tweak what sorts of positions or orgs you're applying to, but don't be discouraged.

Comment: The questions do change after about 6 months. I think the people hiring are trained to pick up on gaps focusing on why you didn't get a job before now.

Answer (score -7):

Do it.

It shows that you have some self awareness and a desire to improve. It also shows that you are able to think outside the box and have the confidence to challenge norms.

When you meet your interviewer say "Hi, I'm paul23", let them introduce themselves, then immediately ask if they would mind if you record the interview. Briefly explain that you struggle with interviews and want to improve on this. Don't mention your history of x many failed interviews. Make it clear that this is your interviewers choice and that if they are uncomfortable about the idea then no video will take place. If possible, make a visual show of putting your recording equipment away if your interviewer displays any kind of hesitation.

Some people will hate this. Other people will decline to be recorded but might be impressed by how you handle a tricky conversation. Some people might actually let you record the interview.

.... but you should definitely do this in a practice interview before you do it to a real person.

Comment: Hopefully someone will offer a contrasting opinion and the votes will tell you how good or bad of an idea this might be.

Comment: If someone asked me *at the start of the interview* if they could video the interview, I'd probably say "no" because it's something I'd need to ask HR about - I don't know whether there's a subtlety here I'm missing, so will take the safe route. Ask me a couple of days before then I'll have had a chance to talk to HR first.

Comment: This isn’t something you can 1. Just do and 2. Do without advanced notice. One it’s likely a violation of privacy or data protection laws without permission and without advanced permission you’re just increasingly likely to not get permission from the interviewer as they will likely need to check internal rules on this (if they have any on this). I’d be willing to bet asking them at the start you will likely get a ‘no’ from them for that reason. Also depending on where you’re located, GDPR is likely to add further complexity.